# How to show result based related tables

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, laravel-8

I'm making a forum with Laravel 8. And for this project, I have a table named `questions` which holds the questions of that have been asked. And I also have a table named `question_user` that shows which user asked which question.

And this is how it looks like:

[image: capture]

Now I want to show the question on blade, so in order to return the name of that `user_id` who asked this question, I coded this:

```
@foreach(\App\Models\Question::all() as $question)
   <div><span class="font-weight-bold">{{ // SHOW USER NAME }}</span></div>
@endforeach
```

Now I don't know what should I add between these curly braces in order to return the username!

Not that I have correctly added the relation between the `User` Model & the `Question` Model.

**Question.php:**

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

**User.php:**

```
public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
    }
```

So how can I show the username of a user who has asked a question based on these relations?

I would really appreciate it if you share your idea or any suggestion...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your structure is wrong; if only one user can ask a particular question, than the user_id should be in the question table, and thus your relation should be ManyToOne from the Question side. but you should be able to something like this in your template: `$question->users()->first()->getUsername()` I can provide a more deatiled explanation if you would like it

Comment: @zedling Please help with this, I really need it

Comment: @zedling now you have both solutions. if you want to use one to many then follow my answer. if you want many to many then you have other answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should totally avoid querying database inside blade views. You should get the data in controllers and then pass it to views or json.

You have to create your `QuestionUser` model to the `question_user` table, but I would name the table like `questions_users`.

And then you should use `hasManyThrough` relation like so:

```
// Question Model

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        User::class,
        QuestionUser::class,
        'question_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'user_id'
    );
}

public function question_users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(QuestionUser::class);
}
```

And then to get User names from Question object, you do it like so:

```
foreach ($question->users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

This loop will execute 1 query to retrieve all of the questions on the table, then another query for each question to retrieve the user. So, if we have 25 questions, this loop would run 26 queries: 1 for the original questions, and 25 additional queries to retrieve the user of question.

You should use eager loading: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading to avoid this!

Answer (score 1):

if you want one to many relationship then follow this. in this case, every question has only one user attached to it and every user can have multiple questions. in short you do not need a foreach loop to show usernames of questions in your blade file.
make a migration with this command.

```
php artisan make:migration add_fk_in_users_table
```

and put this code in there.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('question_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->cascadeOnDelete();
        });
    }
```

add this code in your question model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

and this in your user model.

```
public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
    }
```

you can add questions like this.

```
$user->questions()->saveMany([$question]);
```

you can get user of every question like this. which you really want.

```
$question->user;
```

and user's name like this.

```
$question->user->name;
```

and you will have questions of every user like this

```
$user->questions;
```

it will return an array of collections.